# Generics function return type issue with protocol - Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, generics

I'm studying on generics in Swift and for testing some situations I have this struct and protocol:

```
protocol Vehicle {
    var name: String { get }
}

struct Car: Vehicle {
    let name = "car"
}
```

Then I have this function, and I would to return Car object but I have this function's signature:

```
func wash<T : Vehicle>(_ vehicle: T) -> T{
    return Car()
}
```

but I don't understand because I get this error:

```
Cannot convert return expression of type 'Car' to return type 'T'
```

If I return in this way I remove the error:

```
return Car() as! T
```

Why? Car is already a T type because in the function's signature I insert the constraint that T must be a `Vehicle` type.

Comment: The function signature says that the type of vehicle (subclass) is defined externally, using the parameter `vehicle`. If someone passes something different that a `Car`, e.g. a `Train`, your app will crash.
In other words, when you try to wash a train, you get a washed car. That is probably wrong.

Comment: When you call a generic function, all the `T` get replaced by the type you provided. `wash(Truck()`, for example, should return a `Truck`, not a `Car`. I'd recommend reading into what generic types are, and how they are used, I get the sense that you're missing some important concepts.

Comment: If you are always returning a Car then the function isn't really generic or at least the return type can't be generic

Comment: ok I understood my mistake, How do I give you best response points? Thanks to all